# Ignoring TAB in a IF query

Tags: batch-file

I'm writing a Script that counts every comment line in a Batch Script but I have a problem. Right now it only counts every REM at the start of a line. If there is a REM after one TAB (or more) it doesnt count the line.

```
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
SETLOCAL enableextensions

If "%1"=="" (
ECHO When starting the script, please pass the name of the script to be used as a parameter.
GOTO :eof
)

REM ---------------SETTING_VARIABLES------------------------START-----------------------------------------------------------------------
set Script_Name=%1
set LOGFILE_NAME=%DATE:~-7,2%_%1_SCP_V1.log
set CSV_NAME=%1_SCP_V1.csv
set REM_Counter=0
set ALL_Counter=0
REM ---------------SETTING_VARIABLES------------------------END-----------------------------------------------------------------------


REM ---------------COUNTING_ROWS------------------------START-----------------------------------------------------------------------
FOR /f "tokens=1 delims= " %%a in (.\%Script_Name%) DO (
    set result=false

    IF "%%a"=="REM" (
        set result=true
        )
    IF "%%a"=="@REM" (
        set result=true
        )
    IF "!result!"=="true" (
        set /a REM_Counter=!REM_Counter!+1
        set /a ALL_Counter=!ALL_Counter!+1
        ) else (
            set /a ALL_Counter=!ALL_Counter!+1
            )

)
echo %REM_Counter%
echo %ALL_Counter%
REM ---------------COUNTING_ROWS------------------------END-----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Example Bat:

```
ECHO OFF

    REM 1
    REM 2
    REM 3
    @REM 4
    @REM 5
        REM 6
            REM 7
    bla 
    adwd
     wadg
     g
     awdaw
     daw
```

REM 6 and 7 don't count towards REM_Counter.

Comment: `delims=<tab><space>`?

Comment: Also you might want to use `/i` with the `if`s

Comment: delims=<tab><space> worked. Thank you!

Comment: BTW `Delims=<tab><space>` is the default so you can just stipulate your Tokens, however `Tokens=1` is also the default, so you could leave them both out!

Comment: @stephan you should post that as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just add the TAB to the delimiters: `delims=<tab><space>`

As Compo noted in the comments, TAB and SPACE are the default delimiters (and `tokens=1` also is default), so you can omit both parameters:

```
FOR /f %%a in (.\%Script_Name%) DO (
```

Of course you can keep them for readability (I would).